# A Multilingual Meal

Tags: riddle, wordplay, language

I came up with this one many moons ago but just now got around to sharing it.

You're going out to brunch with your polyglot friend, and, when you ask him what he would like, he says, "I'll have the forty seven point one two four." What is it he wants?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it was my friend, I'd serve him a big fat

> Quince pie. 
>  47.124 is 15*pi (**pie**). 15 in French is Quinze (**quince**)

Comment: This is the correct solution, but as much as I love French, I had a different language in mind when I created this puzzle that more closely connects to the answer. Perhaps you can figure out which.

Comment: @DanTheMan Possibly Catalan.....also quinze

Comment: Or possibly Asturian or Galacian....

Comment: It was Spanish I was thinking of, but those two do the trick as well! I suppose we have those Romans to blame for so many languages having such similar words.

Comment: @DanTheMan Reminds me of an old joke: A guy in a toga walks into a bar, and says "I'll have a martinus".  The bartender replies "You mean 'martini'?"  And he answers "When I want two, I'll ask for two!"

Comment: @DarrelHoffman He also holds up two fingers and says "five beers, please".